# Python Pydantic Error: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

i am currenty working on a python fastapi project for university. Every time i run my authorization dependencies i get the following error:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 366, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 216, in app
    solved_result = await solve_dependencies(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\dependencies\utils.py", line 496, in solve_dependencies
    solved_result = await solve_dependencies(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\dependencies\utils.py", line 525, in solve_dependencies
    solved = await call(**sub_values)
  File "e:\Dev\Ottomize\Ottomize\backend\app\auth_handler.py", line 60, in get_current_user
    token_data = schemas.TokenData(username)
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 322, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

Here is my relevant code:

FAST API Endpoint:

```
@app.get("/user/current/info/", response_model=schemas.User)
async def user_info(current_user: schemas.User = Depends(auth_handler.get_current_active_user)):
    return current_user
```

Used functions in my auth_handler.py:

```
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Optional


from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from . import crud, schemas, config, database

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

#gets user out of db
    def get_user(username: str):
        db = database.SessionLocal()
        return crud.get_user_by_username(db, username)

#gets current user
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, config.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[config.ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = schemas.TokenData(username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user

#gets current user if active
async def get_current_active_user(current_user: schemas.User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user
```

Used functions in my crud.py:

```
def get_user_by_username(db: Session, username: str):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.username == username).first()
```

Used sqlalchemy models:

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String(100), unique=True, index=True)
    mail = Column(String(100), unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String(100))
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    permissions = relationship("Permission", back_populates="user")

class Permission(Base):
    __tablename__ = "permission"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    
    user =  relationship("User", back_populates="permissions")
```

Used pydantic models:

```
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

#Define Datatype Token 
class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str

#Define Datatype TokenData 
class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


#Define Datatype User 
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    mail: str
    is_active: Optional[bool]
    permissions: List[Permission] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I am really new to fastapi and python in general and would really appreciate help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to give Pydantic which *key* you are providing a value for:

```
token_data = schemas.TokenData(username=username)
```

Otherwise Pydantic has no idea that the variable `username` from the parent scope should be assigned to the `username` property in the schema.

Comment: So it looks like Pydantic has implicit keyword only constructor? No positional arguments.

Comment: Having positional arguments would be very prone to errors, since you can't really assume that the sequence of fields in the class remains constant. Do you expect the behaviour to change if you have `username` defined before `name` and just change which field comes first in the class definition? That opens up the possibility of weird and strange bugs (and how would you handle fields with defaults among fields without defaults? In that case all fields with defaults would have to be defined last in your class).

Comment: Could anyone point to me which part of Pydantic documentation website https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/ specifies that we need to provide keyword to its `BaseModel` constructor?

Comment: @hunterex Sorry, I can't give you a reference to the manual (not all negatives and reasons are present in a manual). You can refer to this issue on the Pydantic repository for some of the reasoning from Pydantic's author: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/116 - if you don't need `BaseModel` (but since you asked explicitly about that, I can't really be sure), you could use a dataclass: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/ (or you could just write a helper initializer that takes positional arguments).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used `response_class` instead of `response_model` decorator. It was silly mistake by vscode code suggestion. So just check it in the decorator and change it to `response_model`.

Hope this helps